# The code seems to be fine, but not getting the output. Expected output : Replace text "Heading 1" on browser with array from new.js file

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have 2 files index.html and new.js but could not get the output on browser as expected. The error shows on document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML=fruits; //fruits: name of the array
also tried document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML= fruits.join(", "); //got this from chat gpt

//new.js file content

```
let fruits=["apple","orange","mango"];
fruits.push("kiwi", "grape")
console.log(fruits);
let f1= fruits.indexOf("kiwi");
console.log(f1);
document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML= fruits.join(", ");
```

//index.html file content

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="./new.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="h1">Heading 1</h1>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your h1 is not yet parsed. You are executing your javascript before the element is there, so it doesn’t have any effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try to infer attributes of an element before it exists. You need to make sure your Javascript runs after your HTML element was created. A way to achieve this is to create a `load` event handler that runs when the page has loaded and by that time your HTML element was also created. I therefore wrapped a `load` event handler around your code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
    window.addEventListener('load', function() {
        let fruits=["apple","orange","mango"];
        fruits.push("kiwi", "grape")
        console.log(fruits);
        let f1= fruits.indexOf("kiwi");
        console.log(f1);
        document.getElementById("h1").innerHTML= fruits.join(", ");
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 id="h1">Heading 1</h1>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This issue is occurring because js is executing before the html content has fully loaded. That's why when you try to access the `h1` it returns `null`.

You can either move your `script` tag to the bottom of the `body` tag or you can wrap your js code inside a function and call that function after html has fully loaded to solve this problem.